# Problems with removing objects from an arraylist in processing

Tags: java, object, arraylist, processing

I am fairly new to programming, and I can't get this to work.
It is complicated to explain. There basically is a particle generator that generates a set number of particles. Those particles need to interact with each other, so they all have an ArrayList with all the particles. However, I don't want them to interact with themselves, so I want to remove the object from their ArrayList that is themselves. The storing class still has all the objects in his own Arraylist. The problem is that when I try to let the objects remove one object from their Arraylist, all the objects get removed and the ArrayList of the storing object is also empty. I know I don't have to do this, but I really want to know why it doesn't work and I think it is cleaner if it works this way than when I have to skip one object each time the interacting function runs.
Because it is pretty complicated to describe, it is better to just look at the code.
the code consists of just the code that matters and it is a simplified version. The line: l.remove(n); , is the line that screws everything up.

```java
    G g;
    void setup()
    {size(1000, 600);
    g = new G(10);
    }
    void draw()
    {
      background(255);
      g.displayg();
      text(g.g.size(), 200, 200);
    }
```

first class that is going to be stored in the g class

```java
class D
    {
      int n;
      ArrayList<D> l = new ArrayList<D>();
      D(int input)
      {
        this.n = input;
      }
      void seTup(ArrayList<D> input)
      {
        l = input;
        l.remove(n); //if you delete this line, everything works
      }
      void display()
      {
        fill(0);
        text(this.n, 100+ 10* n, 100);
      }
    }
```

and the storing class

```java
class G
    { int number;
      ArrayList<D> g = new ArrayList<D>();
      G(int inputnumber)
      {this.number = inputnumber;
      for(int i =0; i < number; i++)
      {g.add(new D(i));

      }
      for(int i = g.size()-1; i>=0;i--)
      {
        D x =  g.get(i);
        x.seTup(g);
      }
      }
      void displayg()
      {
        for(D i : g)
        {//text(i.n, 100 + 5*i.n, 100);
          i.display();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that's the remove call for removing by index, not by the object Integer? Also, each particle doesn't need to be comprised of all other particles. Just have the one call that handles all of them iterate over all of them, then loop again and check if the element in the first loop is the element in the second loop and if so, don't execute.

Comment: the remove call removes by index indeed, but the integers match the index in the g ArrayList which is copied into all the objects, so it should remove the right object, and it runs only one time per object (I hope it does). For some reason to remove call only doesn't error when ou put in 0 or n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably because arrays and ArrayLists in Java get shallow copied when you pass them in a method. Essentially what this means is when you pass your ArrayList into a method, instead of making a new ArrayList, it just passes the memory location of your current ArrayList, so changes that take place inside of the method also take place outside of the method. You remove a particle from its own ArrayList which removes it from the top level ArrayList and since you do this to every particle, the top level ArrayList will have no particles left. To solve this you need to make a deep copy method that should look something like this:

```
ArrayList<d> deepCopy(ArrayList<d> original)
{
   ArrayList<d> copiedList = new ArrayList<d>();
   for(int i = 0; i < orginal.size(); i++)
   {
      copiedList.add(original.get(i);
   }
   return copiedList;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right, it seems to work. When the d objects get more data, and for example have moving position, those positions wont change in the copied list? Or will they, because they are still same object?

Comment: Great to hear. For future reference I believe most or all objects in Java are shallow copied, though I do not remember for sure, so keep an eye out for that. The only things I can guarantee are deep copied by default are primitives like int, bool, long, etc.

Comment: Using a deep copy, if you change a position, it will only change for the list you are editing. If you want to update the position in every array when you update it, my best suggestion is, instead of deep copying the array, surround the place you access the array with an if statement that checks if the current index is not equal to the index of the d you are currently modifying. it'd look something like this "if(currentIndex != d.getIndex(){//code here}" there might be a better way to do this, but I cant think of it.

Comment: Nice catch, it is worth noting that a deep can be performed using new ArrayList<T>(Collection<T>) i.e new ArrayList<>(original);